# EF Code First : Best way to identify dynamic proxy

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

What is the best way to know whether my code first entity is from direct code (new DataObject())

or from context (Context.DataObjects.First())

Since i am not preventing my context from using dynamicproxies, i can do that :

```
    protected DataObject()
    {
        if (this.GetType().Namespace != "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
        {
            this.Id = IdGenerator.NextId<DataObject>();
        }
    }
```

but this look like a bad solution, since GetType() is expensive.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the type of the entity you must call `GetType`. Btw. there is recommended solution directly on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835846.aspx). To get ObjectContext instance from DbContext you can use:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```